# How to get commas between concatenated and transposed cells?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Form linked to a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16KbQbgtxddOSXf6QPY9h9OZ77kTSf45AHPQLgpCOkPs/edit#gid=2100307022). It has a number of questions with responses that I need grouped into specific columns. I also need to keep the columns in the order they're in.

I was working with a formula someone helped me with to do one single range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Job Responsibilities";IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(K2:V),,100))))})
```

In Columns H, I, J, it will gather the data in the cells within specified ranges and concatenate them for easier reading at a glance.

I was hoping to find a way to separate the different entries with a comma so that the different values could be picked out easier.

Is there an extra function I can add to my formula in order to separate values with a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this slight change.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Job Responsibilities";IF(A2:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(K2:V&CHAR(10)),,100))),CHAR(10),","))})
```

Comment: Ah, you again! Always glad to have your help, Matt! This resulted in commas for the null values. So it looked like `First Job Responsibilities, , , , , , , , , , , Last Job Responsibilities`

Comment: @JeffAbrahams I put the formula in cell H1 on the MK.Idea tab.  seems to work ok, no?

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right that it is working. I had the null values issue on a row I was filling in manually, but an entry populated by the Google Form seemed to work right. Gonna call it solved for now and evaluate as I go forward. Thanks for coming through for me again!